# How should I reply to this sort of schedule proposal

Tags: new-job, meetings, applications

I got an E-Mail from an employer where I have applied. They asked me when I have time for a meeting in the next 2 weeks. Actually, I could meet at anytime in these 2 weeks so should I write them that they can decide or should I suggest a date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say suggest 3 Dates in the first week and 2 in the second week.

If I were to send someone a request to meet in the next 2 weeks. I want them to give me his/her preferred Dates. I dont care. Perhaps saying "A different date works for me to, but these dates have my preference." even if you dont really do this gives breathing room for them and you actually answered their question properly.

Try to avoid Dates that start at the direct beginnen or close to the end of an workday. This may cause unwanted delays and give an more rushed Meeting.

Answer (score 3):

> They asked me when I have time for a meeting in the next 2 weeks.
>   Actually, I could meet at anytime in these 2 weeks so should I write
>   them that they can decide or should I suggest a date?

They are asking you for a time. So you need to provide one.

You should suggest a date and time that is convenient for you. I tend to prefer mid-morning interviews, since I am a morning person and want to have plenty of time to get there no matter what the morning rush-hour brings. Your mileage may vary.

You might also want to suggest a date within the next week, to help make you appear more interested than it might if you wait until the end of the 2 week period.

Comment: An early date is best, it makes you look keen, and if you wait longer, the job might be gone (depending on the position of course) I've seen people have an interview, get the job, and all other interviews cancelled.